# I need a synonym for "part of"

Tags: word-choice, descriptive-grammar

In the following sentence I need to find a synonym for "part of". Also I don't like how "construe" sounds in the sentence.

> The sociological perspective of structuralism *construes* aspects of society as being *part of a* cohesive and self-sustainable system.

Comment: If you elaborate on why you don't like *construe* in the sentence and why you need a synonym of *part of*, it will be a much better question.

Comment: i have to paraphrase to avoid plagiarism " part of " is in original text as  is  the word "views rather than construes.

Comment: "... as elements of a ..." (or *components*).

Comment: Uh, plagiarism isn't avoided with the use of an occasional synonym.

Comment: Plagiarism is not presenting another's words as your own but presenting another's thoughts as your own. Don't bother paraphrasing: give the original in quotes and provide the citation, which is obligatory in any case.

Comment: A object is *comprised* of its parts.  The parts are *components* of the object.

Comment: Thank you all for your time and comments, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

> The sociological perspective of structuralism *interprets* aspects of society as being *elements* of a cohesive and self-sustainable system.

Answer (score 0):

Consider,

*The sociological perspective of structuralism interprets aspects of society as **belonging (or pertaining) to** a cohesive and self- sustainable system.*

> belong (to): to be an attribute, part, adjunct or function of a person or thing [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/belong)